# Rotate Image to align features with X-axis in OpenCV Python

Tags: python, opencv

In the following microscopy image, I extracted the horizontal white line grid using morphological operators in OpenCV. I couldn't completely get rid of the noise which is why there are some white lines in-between. The grid lines need to be parallel to the x-axis. During the microscopic reading process, perfect parallelism cannot be ensured. In this case, the lines are moving slightly upwards from left to right.
How can I realign the lines to the x-axis so that they are parallel to the lower and upper edges of the image using OpenCV or any other Python package?

I'm relatively new to OpenCV so if anyone could give me a hint what operations or functions would be helpful to tackle this problem, I'd be grateful.

Thanks!

[image: White lines on a black grid]

Comment: Do you want to do the alignment before or after the mophological operation? Can you upload the preprocessed image?

Comment: *why* alignment? this is close enough to establish a grid order. extract the individual ROIs relative to each marker bar.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz you are right. For this sample, this approach would also work and was actually my initial approach. But this image is only one region of a sample. Other areas have many more noisy lines than this one so that the grid gets lost. So I thought I find an area where the grid lines are clearly identifiable like this one, extract the rotation matrix, and then rotate the whole image. If the grid lines are parallel to the x-axis, it is easy to track them even if they are not visible in the noise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may fit lines, get the mean angle and rotate the image.

The suggested solution uses the following stages:

- Threshold (binarize) the image.
- Apply closing morphological operation for connecting the lines.
- Find contours.
- Iterate the contours and fit a line for each contour.
  Compute the angle of each line, and build a list of angles.
- Compute the mean angle of the angles that are "close to the median angle".
- Rotate the image by the mean angle.

---

Here is the code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import math

img = cv2.imread("input.png", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)  # Read input image as grayscale.

threshed = cv2.threshold(img, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]  # threshold (binarize) the image

# Apply closing for connecting the lines
threshed = cv2.morphologyEx(threshed, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, np.ones((1, 10)))

# Find contours
contours = cv2.findContours(threshed, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)[-2]  # [-2] indexing takes return value before last (due to OpenCV compatibility issues).

img2 = cv2.cvtColor(threshed, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)  # BGR image - used for drawing

angles = []  # List of line angles.

# Iterate the contours and fit a line for each contour
# Remark: consider ignoring small contours
for c in contours:
    vx, vy, cx, cy = cv2.fitLine(c, cv2.DIST_L2, 0, 0.01, 0.01) # Fit line
    w = img.shape[1]
    cv2.line(img2, (int(cx-vx*w), int(cy-vy*w)), (int(cx+vx*w), int(cy+vy*w)), (0, 255, 0))  # Draw the line for testing
    ang = (180/np.pi)*math.atan2(vy, vx) # Compute the angle of the line.
    angles.append(ang)

angles = np.array(angles)  # Convert angles to NumPy array.

# Remove outliers and 
lo_val, up_val = np.percentile(angles, (40, 60))  # Get the value of lower and upper 40% of all angles (mean of only 10 angles)
mean_ang = np.mean(angles[np.where((angles >= lo_val) & (angles <= up_val))])

print(f'mean_ang = {mean_ang}')  # -0.2424

M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D((img.shape[1]//2, img.shape[0]//2), mean_ang, 1)  # Get transformation matrix - for rotating by mean_ang

img = cv2.warpAffine(img, M, (img.shape[1], img.shape[0]), cv2.INTER_CUBIC) # Rotate the image

# Display results
cv2.imshow('img2', img2)
cv2.imshow('img', img)
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

---

Result:
`img2` (for testing):
[image]

`img` (after rotating):
[image]

---

Note:

- The code is just an example - I don't expect it to solve all of your microscopy images.